# How to generate Html file with Mjml framework in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, mailkit, mjml

I am sending an e-mail using mailkit and mimekit like this:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("najmahan", "santosh.metikoti@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("najmahan.com"));
message.Subject = "Transactions between " + startDate + "and " + endDate;

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = $"<table><tr><th>Account</th><th>Amount</th><th>Date</th><th>Type</th></tr>";

foreach (var item in model.AllTransactions)
{
    /*Console.WriteLine(item.Account_Name + "-" + item.Amount + "-" + item.Date);*/
    bodyBuilder.HtmlBody += $"<tr><td>{item.Account_Name}</td><td>{item.Amount}</td><td>{item.Date}</td><td>{item.Type}</td></tr>";
}

foreach (var item in model.IncomeLists)
{
    bodyBuilder.HtmlBody += $"<b>Total Income: {item.Income}</b><br>";
}

foreach (var item in model.ExpenseLists)
{
    bodyBuilder.HtmlBody += $"<b>Total Expense: {item.Expense}</b><br>";
}

bodyBuilder.TextBody = "This is some plain text";

var prehtml = "<mjml><mj-body><mj-container><mj-section><mj-column><mj-text>Hello World!</mj-text></mj-column></mj-section></mj-container></mj-body></mjml>";

message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

In this by using `bodyBuilder.HtmlBody`. I wanted to use MJML(responsive email framework) which should generate HTML text and append with `message`.

How can I do this. if there is just a default mjml code generated and append with `message` will also help

Please help me with this

Comment: What issue currently you are having with? As your email body would be as `string` so could you try with `stringBuilder` in `C#` then design the `html` as you want finally append the stringBuilder into the email body. Please have  a try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. To solve it, I found two optimal options:

1. [unofficial port of MJML 4 (by MailJet)](https://github.com/SebastianStehle/mjml-net). Made entirely on .Net. Does not support two components (**mj-include** and **mj-html-attributes**)
2. [mjml-aspnetcore](https://github.com/mjml-aspnetcore/mjml-aspnetcore) - uses nodejs. Full support for the mjml standard. Should be slower than the first version, requires installation of nodejs and mjml

For first option solution will look like

```
var mjmlRenderer = new MjmlRenderer();
message.Body = mjmlRenderer.Render(prehtml, new MjmlOptions {
    Beautify = false
}).Html;
```

ps. I apologize that the solution is not complete - copying code examples from github is a bad in my opinion.